# Is it okay to make predictions without using all regressors?

Tags: regression, time-series, predictive-models

Currently, I am looking at a time series model (linear regression) that has 5 independent variables. The owner of the model says only 3 regressors are fed with input and predictions are made using only those 3. The two that are left out are AR and MA terms.

I wonder whether is it EVER okay to do that?

Comment: For prediction? Sure, if it works it works.

Comment: I'm voting to close. This is close enough to a real question to confuse others. You need to say more about what the model is for, what it's supposed to do (optimal MSE? optimal AUC?), and how the statistician used the data to do this, and what the strategy was to validate their approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it EVER OK" isn't a good way of asking. You can do lots of things in statistics and how "OK" this is will always depend on what use you make of the results and what implications this has. Here what is proposed will achieve a certain quality of prediction, and then the question is whether this is good enough for the specific situation, whether the 2 further variables would substantially improve it, and what would be the cost of including them.